# Calculating P-Value

Tags: r

How to calculate the P-Value using "t-sample t-test" and "Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney test" for the following data:

```
died<-mydata[mydata$disoutcome=="died"]
survived<-mydata[mydata$disoutcome=="recovered"]
mean_died<-sapply(died,mean,na.rm=T)
SD_died<-apply(died,2,sd,na.rm=T)
mean_survived<-sapply(survived,mean,na.rm=T)
SD_survived<-apply(survived,2,sd,na.rm=T)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can just use the `t.test()` function or `wilcox.test()` function and R will calculate p scores.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `t.test` and `wilcox.test` functions

Comment: thanks for your reply. I know the format of t.test(x). what is X ?

Answer (score 0):

Those functions can already handle data in a data frame. In your example, it looks like `disoutcome` is a factor with levels `died` and `recovered`. If you have another column `measurement` with the measurement you want to compare, you just need to use

`t.test(data=mydata, measurement~disoutcome)`

or

`wilcox.test(data=mydata, measurement~disoutcome)`

Each of these will return a summary of the results, including P value. Or if you don't care about the summary you can just extract the P value with `$pvalue`. Consult `?t.test` or `?wilcox.test` for more information.